# Bash - read log file in real time and execute command on error message

Tags: bash, logging, grep, pipe, tail

I've been trying to read a log file in real time which sometimes contains one or more different error messages. A colleague sent me a command that, once the word "error" appears, it should update another log (a status log) with a specific number, in this case the number 2. 
Here's the command:

`$(tail -n0 -f /Users/user/Desktop/file | grep error | echo 2 > /Users/user/Desktop/error.log) &`

The problem is: this command ***always*** updates error.log with the number 2, whether my file's last line was an error warning word or not. Moreover, if I try the following shorter command

`$ tail -n0 -f /Users/user/Desktop/file | grep error`

and *echo* a random word to my file, it still appears on the *tail*, so it definitely isn't filtering new lines in real time. Can you help?

Thanks

Comment: Is the use of bash and std-tools like grep a requirement? Because is a real language like Python or Java this can be done in a view lines.

Comment: Unfortunately...yes :( I wish I had that chance, this has been pretty annoying. The oddest thing is that
`$ tail -n0 -f /Users/user/Desktop/file | grep error`
simply doesn't work, any message I add to my file appears on the tail and it should only update with error messages. I'm pretty clueless right now.

Comment: Sorry for double posting, but I forgot to mention I was on MacOS. I just tried the commands on a Ubuntu system and it worked flawlessly. I had no idea there could be a difference in implementation but I hope this helps anyone who has come upon this problem. I still have no solution, but at least now I know the problem.

Comment: You are piping the output from `grep` *into* `echo`, which does not read it.  The `|` is a pipe, not an "or".

Comment: I fixed the first issue by installing grep through brew, which installs the GNU grep. Now it works properly. 
thanks for the hint, @cdarke . You're right and the echo occurs every time, which it shouldn't. Do you have any idea on how to only update error.log once grep finds a match? Thanks a lot.